# WINDOWS 7 | Backup & Restore | limit number of backups (quantity)

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, configure, rate-limits

`win7_6.1.7601.sp1
Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore`

I ended up finding out the hard way that Windows 7's **Backup and Restore** is an essential function. Where a user can define where to store backups and what to actually backup. Those are good options for basic configuring, but what happens if Windows 7 continues to just keep backing up if a schedule is set and you run out of space?

**Is there a way to limit the number of backups?** Preferably I want *8-backups per month* with 2-backups *happening each week* for 4-weeks at a time. After four weeks has past then the 1st backup of the month will be removed in place of the new #1 backup out of #8 total (*subject to change, but used as an example*).

Again, i'm trying to not use too much space but have enough backups to help me out, but not run me out.

### PROBLEM

- Unable to set how many backups max to avoid losing space for a 1-month period

  - Duration: 1-month is 8-backups (*or backups twice a week*)

### SOLUTION

- None-so-far

NOTE

- After initial backup or backup-activated then restore file

  - `right-click -> properties -> Previous Versions (tab)`
- Choosing directory for backups seems to be limited to only selecting drives

  - Saving in drives root folder is messy without an option to have a parent directory for what the backup is even about, so only saving it to a network-path allows the option of custom directory
- Restoring only work if filename is the same

  - Restore only reads *last-modified* & *file-size*
- Changing how frequent backup schedules occur

  - Normal option is a single reoccuring date & time; otherwise, [manually changing it by including more schedules via Task Scheduler](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-how-often-system-restore-creates-restore-points-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: How much space have you allocated to Previous Versions?  You might be shocked at how much space this will require.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to even do that. I chose what to backup and only check marked the typical My Documents, Downloads, Music, Video, etc. as what Backup&Restore refers to as `Data Files` Whole entire drives are known as `Computer (files)`. My total output size is 1GB.

Comment: It would be under, System Protection, for the drive in question.  The amount of space you allocate, determines, how far fact your file history can go and how many restore points.  As far as limiting the number of backups, its limited by space, if you want more configuration options use a third-party program with those options.

Comment: System Protection is not a good way to bring *that* window up. Just run `sysdm.cpl` and you can [change setting](https://i.postimg.cc/Jn14hFH6/20180925_101824.png) per drive. In my case just did two-notches to the right and it goes by 5gb per notch ended up being 13GB. I'm accounting for PC's that will have a lot of files so I know who has more than 10gb on what machine to begin with.

Comment: If you have your own answer, post it as an answer. Don't try to reinvent how the website works.

Comment: I didn't know the answer at first. Thanks to Ramhound, now I do. Is there a reason why I got a negative reaction to this post?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you know the answer upfront or discover it weeks later. Post it as an answer using the "Answer your question" button below, where it belongs. Don't litter the content with changelogs; the site has an edit history already.

Comment: The public doesn't get to see this information, though. I think it's the strangest thing when someone can read it quicker because less clicks is less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Back & Restore has an option to limit number of backups based off Disk Space Usage (configure below):

System Properties -> System Protection (tab) via sysdm.cpl -> select drive -> Configure

check Restore system settings and previous versions of files

set Disk Space Usage (I set it as ~9gb to match my criteria of 4-weeks with 2perweek)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for network shares :-/